# WordPress - Ajax Request Keeps Returning 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I can't seem to figure out why nothing is returned from my ajax call (returns a 0). What I'm trying to do is when a user fills out their LAN ID on a form, their supervisor's information auto populates a few fields. Any help/suggestions is much appreciated. Here's my code:

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ldapattr', 'get_ldap_attr');

jQuery(function() {

```
jQuery('#empLanId').on('blur', function() {

    var lanid = jQuery('#empLanId').val(),
        data = { action: "get_ldap_attr", lanid: lanid };

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('error');
            }

        });

});
```

});

function get_ldap_attr($lanid) {

```
$dn = get_site_option ( "ldapServerOU" );
$usr = get_site_option ( "ldapServerCN" );
$pw = get_site_option ( "ldapServerPass" );
$addr = get_site_option ( "ldapServerAddr" );
$ids = array();
$ad = ldap_connect ( $addr )
    or die ( "Connection error." );
ldap_set_option ( $ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 );
ldap_set_option ( $ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0 );
$bind = ldap_bind ( $ad, $usr, $pw );

if ( $bind ) {
    $SearchFor ="cn=".$lanid;
        $result = ldap_search ( $ad,$dn,$SearchFor );

        $entry = ldap_first_entry ( $ad, $result );
        if ( $entry != false )  {
            $info = ldap_get_attributes ( $ad, $entry );
        }
        $comm  = stripos ( $info['directReports'], ',' );
            // find position of first comma in CN=Mxxxxxx,OU=Users,OU=MCR,DC=mfad,DC=mfroot,DC=org  (directReports field)
        $eq = stripos ( $info['directReports'], '=' );
            // find position of first =
        $s_lanid = substr ( $info['directReports'], $eq+1, ( ( $comm-1 ) - ( $eq ) ) );
            //get substring between = and comma... for lanid happiness..
        $sup = getLDAP ( $s_lanid, $ad, $dn, $usr, $pw );
            // get supervisor's info...
}

//return $sup;

echo json_encode($sup); die();
```

Comment: If you end with `die(json_encode(array( 'test' => 'value' )))` does your console show that array? Validating that your `$sup` variable isn't the problem.

Comment: Even if you _start_ `get_ldap_attr()` with that?

Comment: I'm receiving my object's data but when I feed it through ajax, it still returns a 0...

Comment: Are you testing while logged in as admin perhaps?

Comment: Add add_action('wp_ajax_get_ldapattr', 'get_ldap_attr');

Answer (score 2):

If your `$sup` variable is valid and populated after your site option retrieval and parsing, you need to actually `echo` out the `JSON` - not return it.

Example in your code:

```
return json_encode($sup); die();
```

..should read:

```
echo json_encode($sup);
die();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried that also, but still not luck.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

if you write

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_**get_ldapattr**', '**get_ldap_attr**');
```

so you have to call `get_ldapattr` and not `get_ldap_att`.

In other words, if you specify

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_**ACTION_HANDLER**', '**CALLBACK_FUNCTION**');
```

you have to call `ACTION_HANDLER` in your ajax js script (unless `ACTION_HANDLER` coincides with `CALLBACK_FUNCTION`)

Answer (score 0):

that's because it returns results from conditional that checks if user is logged as admin. 
0 is false.

Update: 
Try instead of return on end of the function, to put echo or print results. I think you end function procedure, but other processes from wp keep getting still.

Comment: ...there is no conditional check to see if a user is an admin in his code.

Comment: that's true, but I pointed out to wordpress core, that has that conditional :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "header" section.
Your PHP script should end like this:

```
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json' ); // <<------
    echo json_encode($sup);
    die();
```